# Irreducible polynomial with $\alpha^l=\beta^l \in \mathbb{Q}$ for any two roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, irreducible-polynomials, rational-numbers

Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $\alpha^l=\beta^l \in \mathbb{Q}$ for any two roots $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ of $f$. Can I follow $f | (x^l-\alpha^l)$ from this? If $\deg f \leq l$, the statement is obvious. But is $\deg f > l$ possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c=\alpha^l$ and $g(X)=X^l-c$. As $f$ is irreducible, $\gcd(f,g)$ is either $1$ or $f$ itself. In the latter case, of course $f\mid g$ and $\deg f\le \deg g=l$. In the first case, $f$ has *no* root in common with $g$, whereas all roots of $f$ must be roots of $g$; then $f$ has no roots at all and is constant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Why does $f$ not have a common zero in the first case? Because you can find in this case $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $1=pf+qg$?